What is the motivation for the use of $n-m$ in the method of moments in Wedderburn 1974?
In an answer to this question Is there a Relationship Between Variance and Chi-Square?
I wrote

So to find the dispersion parameter, one has to use a different trick. In Wedderburn 1974 this is done by using the method of moments.
The expectation of the variance is approximately:
$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\mu_i)^2}{V(\mu_i)} \right] \approx \phi({n-m})$$
(The approximation is based on assuming that $V(\mu_i)$ is approximately linear and that the distribution is $\chi^2$ distributed)

In the above quote the expression computes the sum of squared residuals, $(x_i-\mu_i)^2$, weighted by the estimated variance (which for GLM can be expressed by a function of the mean), $V(\mu_i)$. The $\phi$ is a dispersion coefficient, $n$ is the number of observations and $m$ is the number of eatimated parameters.
The part in the brackets is not correct (I am removing it). The distribution is not $\chi^2$ distributed. That's for a normal distribution family, but not in general.
But it also doesn't need to be. What matters for the method of moments is just that the distribution has that expectation value.
What I am wondering however is:
Is the expectation value of the sum of scaled squared residuals equal to the sample size $n$ minus the parameters $m$?
And how can we prove it? It if it is only approximately true, how do we show that the approximation is reasonable?
We do have that the residuals are in a smaller subspace (like described here: Why are the residuals in $\mathbb{R}^{n-p}$?), but the distribution of the errors is not spherically symmetric and the variance may not need to partition equally.

What is this quantity that you're calling $m$?

What is "$\phi$"?  The notation doesn't even reveal whether it's a multiplicative constant or a function!

I can imagine that the estimates $\hat{y}$ are approximately a linear function of the observations, and the variance of the estimate becomes $n-m$, the rank of the matrix that describes the linear function.

Here's some intuition that also provides an outline of a more rigorous demonstration: when you linearize the GLM it becomes a WLS problem; the approximation given here is the expectation for that approximate solution, which is intuitively obvious when compared to the corresponding OLS formula.

@whuber I guess it is gonna work out like that. Some sort of linear approximation. I don't have a full grasp of it yet however, I have to draw it out in some images and examples. I am not looking for a rigorous demonstration, but just the intuition.
